# Nokogiri Scraping In Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

So I have this code in my index action, would love to move it to a model, just a little confused on how to do it.

### Original Code

```
  def index
    urls = %w[http://cltampa.com/blogs/potlikker http://cltampa.com/blogs/artbreaker http://cltampa.com/blogs/politicalanimals http://cltampa.com/blogs/earbuds http://cltampa.com/blogs/dailyloaf http://cltampa.com/blogs/bedpost]
    @final_images = []
    @final_urls = []
    
    urls.each do |url|
      blog = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url)) 
      images = blog.xpath('//*[@class="postBody"]/div[1]//img/@src')
      images.each do |image|
        @final_images << image
      end
      
      story_path = blog.xpath('//*[@class="postTitle"]/a/@href')
      story_path.each do |path|
        @final_urls << path
      end
    end  
  end
```

I tested this code in my model and it works perfectly for one url, just not sure how to integrate all of the urls like the original code.

### New Code

### Model

```
class Photocloud < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_reader :url, :data

  def initialize(url)
    @url = url
  end

  def data
    @data ||= Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  end

  def get_elements(path)
    data.xpath(path)
  end

end
```

### Controller

```
def index 
  @scraper = Photocloud.new('http://cltampa.com/blogs/artbreaker')
  @photos = @scraper.get_elements('//*[@class="postBody"]/div[1]//img/@src')
  @story_urls = @scraper.get_elements('//*[@class="postBody"]/div[1]//img/@src')
end
```

My main questions are how would I initialize multiple urls and loop through them like my original code. I have tried different things but feel like I have hit a wall. I need to save them to the database, but would like to get this working first. Any help is greatly appreciated.

### Updated Controller - WIP

```
  def index
    start_urls = %w[http://cltampa.com/blogs/potlikker 
      http://cltampa.com/blogs/artbreaker 
      http://cltampa.com/blogs/politicalanimals 
      http://cltampa.com/blogs/earbuds 
      http://cltampa.com/blogs/dailyloaf 
      http://cltampa.com/blogs/bedpost]
    @scraper = Photocloud.new(start_urls)
    @images = 
    @paths = 
  end
```

Need some help with this part...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you don't persist scraped images and paths to the database so `Photocloud` doesn't need to inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base` - it can be just a plain old ruby object (PORO):

```
class Photocloud
  attr_reader :start_urls
  attr_accessor :images, :paths

  def initialize(start_urls)
    @start_urls = start_urls
    @images = []
    @paths = []
  end

  def scrape
    start_urls.each do |start_url|
      blog = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
      scrape_images(blog)
      scrape_paths(blog)
    end
  end

  private
  def scrape_images(blog)
    images = blog.xpath('//*[@class="postBody"]/div[1]//img/@src')
    images.each do |image|
      images << image
    end
  end

  def scrape_paths(blog)      
    story_path = blog.xpath('//*[@class="postTitle"]/a/@href')
    story_path.each do |path|
      paths << path
    end
  end
end
```

In controller:

```
scraper = Photocloud.new(start_urls)
scraper.scrape
@images = scraper.images
@paths = scraper.paths
```

This is only one of the possibilities how you could structure code, of course.

Comment: Hi @Andrius, thank you for the help, greatly appreciated. I added an Updated Controller section to my code above, any chance you'd take a look and give some insight? Trying to set it up based on what you've showed me.

Comment: Thank you again, for some reason I am getting an empty array for my photos after updated the controller, but I am working on it.

Comment: I had to update the private methods to use instance variables and it works fine now.